# Sharing jQuery code for header and footer includes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to dynamically include some navigation bars, format and misc css classes via jQuery.

For each webpage I have the following code :-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" >    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#navigation').load('navigationtheory.html');
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#footer').load('../../include/footer.html');
    });
    $(function(){ $("head").load("../../include/header.html") });
</script>
```

This is inside the `<head>` dom element.

I have to isolate the second script contents into a separate file. I did so by including the exact code in a file called jqueryincludes.js and then call it in this fashion

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>
 <script src="jqueryincludes.js"> </script>
```

My contents of jquery includes is :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navigation').load('navigationtheory.html');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#footer').load('../../include/footer.html');
});
$(function(){ $("head").load("../../include/header.html") });
```

The page does not render correctly.

So in theory this should work. I am pretty certain its a syntax error, I could not find anything in jQuery documentation for external definitions.

I am new to Javascript and JQuery.

Comment: What error message do you get if you use Google Chrome's Inspector-tool?

Comment: Path issue. That was embarrassing. Thanks.

Comment: Not the error, but you don't need three separate document ready handlers in the script. Put all three load() statements into a single ready handler.